# SSRS Datepicker control is not showing in Chrome and safari

Tags: reporting-services, datepicker, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS for reports in asp.net application. SSRS Datepicker control is not showing in Chrome and safari. It is just displaying the textbox.

Comment: Good question. Not sure you'll get much...   :(

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/a96537e3-0945-4046-816b-5eb0d8875dd3/

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use I.E.

I always use a default value so the user knows how to imput the date correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear this. There will be limited you can do apart from work arounds as this is meant for Microsoft. :(

Mine is forget the date parameter type and use a free text field. In no way is this ideal!

Or use Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ietab chrome extension whenever I access reporting services reports. It works beautifully with reporting services.
[link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en)

Answer (score -2):

**Solution for Chrome**:  If the parameter's prompt contains the word "date" Chrome will display the calendar control.

*(note: this is true for any parameter regardless of the parameters actual datatype)*